# Can't access mvn command from command line?

Tags: maven, installation, maven-3

I've tried to access **mvn** from command line.

*Installation path*

```
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.1.1
```

*User variables*

```
M2 = %M2_HOME%\bin 
M2_HOME = C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.1.1
JAVA_HOME = C:\Archivos de programa\Java\jdk1.7.0_25
```

*System variables*

```
Path = %M2%;%JAVA_HOME%/bin; and others...
```

I try to se if Maven is well configured through mvn --version as the manual says but this is the result:

```
C:\>mvn --version
"mvn" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.

C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.1.1\bin>mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.1.1 (0728685237757ffbf44136acec0402957f723d9a; 2013-09-17 17:22:22+0200)
Maven home: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.1.1
Java version: 1.7.0_25, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Archivos de programa\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre
Default locale: es_ES, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows xp", version: "5.1", arch: "x86", family: "windows"
```

What could it be this? Should I export the variables every time I need them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Path = %M2%;%JAVA_HOME%/bin; and others...
```

If you change `%M2%` to `%M2_HOME%\bin` it'll work.

To be precise: if you execute 'set Path' it must contain the path to the bin directory of Maven.

Comment: And you have to open a new command prompt after setting these values!

Comment: no luck :(
C:\>set path
Path=%M2_HOME%\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;%JAVA_HOME%\bin

PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.bat

C:\>mvn --version
"mvn" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.

Comment: You shouldn't mix user variables and system variables. You can also use the `Path` user variable: `Path` `%M2%;%JAVA_HOME%/bin;` Windows will concat them correctly.

Comment: System variables can not access user variables! That was the mistake.

Answer (score 2):

In my past I was the same (Windows 7) and I solved it by running the cmd as administrator. Click Start - Accessories - click Command System right click `Run as Administrator`

Answer (score 0):

```
export M2_HOME=/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.3.9
export M2=$M2_HOME/bin
export PATH=$M2:$PATH

mvn --version
```

**Note:** Set Java path if not available

Comment: This can be used in mac or linux

Comment: @lakru-one I used it in Mac; most probably it will work in both platforms